# unknown comodel_name 'product.product'

Tags: many-to-one, odoo-9

Going crazy:

I'm simply trying to add a many2one field in my custom module. (module from scratch, does not inherit from others or expand others yet).

`light_system = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Lighting System', ondelete='restrict')`

when I restart the server I get:

`WARNING newtest openerp.fields: Field jobsite.location.light_system with unknown comodel_name 'product.product'`

And when I try to select something from that field in a form if fails with:

`ProgrammingError: relation "_unknown" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "_unknown".id FROM "_unknown" ORDER BY "_unknown"."id...`

The same happens if I use product.template. If i change 'product.product' to 'res.partner' it works just fine (for contacts)...

What am I missing here? I've searched and googled, the lack of like problems makes me think I'm missing something really simple what model am I supposed to use for products?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was missing the 'product' string in the 'depends' list in **openerp**.py

Answer (score 0):

you will added **'depends'** list in openerp.py and then absolute working Fine. Thank You.